# can't catch Exception

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

When I start my tests I want to see an Exception, but programm just stay on the one line "mobileTelephony.driver" and don't throught exception. I don't understand why?

```
@Test(groups = {"non-basic"})
@Parameters({"idCategory"})
public void checkSearchForm(int idCategory) throws InterruptedException {


String categoryName;
    int location = 1;
    StackOfCategories sub1Stack = TestSuiteMobileTelephony.sub1Stack;   
    boolean isItSubCategory;

basePage.getBasePage();

basePage.clickCategoryName(idCategory);
MobileTelephonyPage mobileTelephony = PageFactory.initElements(basePage.driver, MobileTelephonyPage.class);

while (location <= 3) {
    mobileTelephony.clickChangeLocation(location);
    for(int i = 1; i <= sub1Stack.size(); i++) {
        if (location == 1) {
            categoryName = sub1Stack.getCategory(i).getNameEn();
        } else if (location == 2) {
            categoryName = sub1Stack.getCategory(i).getNameRu();
        } else {
            categoryName = sub1Stack.getCategory(i).getNameUk();
        }

        mobileTelephony.writeInSearchFormAndClick(categoryName);

        try {
            mobileTelephony.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='breadcrumbs']/span1"));
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            mobileTelephony.back();
        }
        isItSubCategory = true;

        AssertMessage.assertTrueNavigateSubCategory(categoryName, isItSubCategory);
        mobileTelephony.back();
    }
    location++;
}
```

}
Mobail Telefony code
public class MobileTelephonyPage extends BasePage {

```
public void clickAndWriteNumber(String number) throws AWTException {

    String[] numsArray = number.split("");

    number1.clear();
    number1.click();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    // Constryction
    for(int i = 0; i < numsArray.length; i++) {

        switch(Integer.parseInt(numsArray[i])) {
            case 0 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                break;
            case 1 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                break;
            case 2 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                break;
            case 3 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                break;
            case 4 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                break;
            case 5 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                break;
            case 6 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
                break;
            case 7 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
                break;
            case 8 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
                break;
            case 9 :
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
                break;
        }
    }       
}

public MobileTelephonyPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public int getHeightImg(int number) {
    int height = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//div[@class='icon']/img)[" + number + "]")).getSize().getHeight();
    return height;  
}

public int getWidthImg(int number) {
    int width = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//div[@class='icon']/img)[" + number + "]")).getSize().getWidth();
    return width;
}

public MobileTelephonyPage back() {
    driver.navigate().back();
    return this;
}

public String getCurrentURL() {
    return driver.getCurrentUrl();
}

public void clickOperator(String linkText) {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
}
```

}

in debug program stop in the next snipet of code(class HttpCommandExecutor)

```
    this.log("profiler", new HttpProfilerLogEntry(command.getName(), true));
    HttpResponse e = this.client.execute(httpRequest, true);
    this.log("profiler", new HttpProfilerLogEntry(command.getName(), false));
```

Comment: If the code of MobileTelephonyPage is a custom code post it. Or if it a library post informations on the library

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO added!

Comment: So MobileTelephonyPage is custom. Well WebDriver is also custom? If yes post the code of the function findElement

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I'm creating WebDriver but findElement it's a function of driver https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I added what I see in debug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Exception is thrown.

Probably the code needs a long time to be executed or it is in a livelock.

A *livelock* is a situation when a function is executed but never ends. For example because in a for loop you loose to update a variable so the test is always true

Edited after new informations

From the javadoc of `WebDriver`:

> This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the
>   time of execution. The findElement(..) invocation will return a
>   matching row, **or try again repeatedly until the configured timeout is**
>   **reached**. findElement **should not be used to look for non-present**
>   **elements**, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response
>   instead.

As you can see the the function could not returns exactly as mentioned on the first two lines of my post.

Comment: if xpath is right all work fine but if not right i can't catch Exception